# Node JS Client Side Code To Download File

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following node js code that dumps mysql database and save the zip file on server:

```
            /* DUMP - database */
            var mysqldump = child_process.exec(['mysqldump -u root --password='+db_pass+' '+db_name+' | zip --password '+db_zip+' > '+process.env.PWD+'/'+rows[0].name+'-'+date+'.zip']);

            /* DUMP - zip created */
            mysqldump.on('exit', function(){
                /* DOWNLOAD - backup zip */
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename='+rows[0].name+'-'+date+'.zip',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-gzip',
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
                });

                /* PIPE - backup zip */
                var zip = fs.createReadStream(process.env.PWD+'/'+rows[0].name+'-'+date+'.zip', 'utf-8').pipe(res);

                /* DELETE - backup zip */
                zip.on('finish', function() {
                    fs.unlink(process.env.PWD+'/'+rows[0].name+'-'+date+'.zip', function() {});
                    res.end();
                });
            });
```

File is successfully created on server but i need client side code to download this file..if i put manually link in chrome to download file it downloads file...i try using:

```
location ='http://'+window.location.host+'/backup';
```

it downloads file but when opening zip file it says wrong header and file is corrupt...so the question is:

how can i read on client side in javascript that file and save it with zip extension so that file is correct downloaded? Something that reading pipe output binary and save it when download is complete as zip file on client side.

UPDATED Full Server Code:

```
/**
 * DEFINE
 * @backup create
 */
panel.get('/backup', function(req, res) {

        /* DEFINE - variables */
        var date = new Date().getFullYear() + "" + ("0" + (new Date().getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "" + ("0" + (new Date().getDate())).slice(-2);

        /* READ - settings */
        pool.query("SELECT name FROM settings",function(err, rows, fields){
            /* CHECK - error */
            if (err) {
                res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : err});
                return;
            };
            /* FOUND - settings */
            if (rows.length) {
                /* DUMP - database */
                var mysqldump = child_process.exec(['mysqldump -u root --password='+db_pass+' '+db_name+' | zip --password '+db_zip+' > '+process.env.PWD+'/'+rows[0].name+'-'+date+'.zip']);

                /* DUMP - zip created */
                mysqldump.on('exit', function(){
                    /* DOWNLOAD - backup zip */
                    res.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename='+rows[0].name+'-'+date+'.zip',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-gzip',
                        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
                    });

                    /* PIPE - backup zip */
                    var zip = fs.createReadStream(process.env.PWD+'/'+rows[0].name+'-'+date+'.zip', 'utf-8').pipe(res);

                    /* DELETE - backup zip */
                    zip.on('finish', function() {
                        fs.unlink(process.env.PWD+'/'+rows[0].name+'-'+date+'.zip', function() {});
                        res.end();
                    });
                });
            } else {
                /* RETURN - settings error */
                res.json({"status": "false", "message": "Backup NOT Available!"});
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: app.static("/backup"), please provide your webserver code...

Comment: Here you go...i updated full server code that generates mysql dump and pipe it out to client..so now i don't know how to read that file from client using /backup api and save it as zip....

Comment: I dont know whats wrong with your code. However, you could make your life easier by using res.download(zipUrl);

Comment: thanks....this code above works on server side..i need client code so that it can download when i click on button Backup....so how can i on client side download that file and save it in chrome browser? I try using: location ='http://'+window.location.host+'/backup'; but i get corrupted zip file when i opened it in winrar

Comment: <a href="/backup">Download Backup</a> there should be no clientside code necessary

Comment: I added <a href="/backup">Download Backup</a> and file is downloaded when i try to open in winrar i get Bad zip header found. error message...so i think that somewhere is the error...but could not find it

Comment: When i put manually link in chrome: http://58.112.36.57:6060/backup it downloads file but same error Bad zip header found..when i download zip file manually with wincsp from server and try to open it opens correctly in winrar without error..so i think the problem is in server side code maybe header for zip is not good?